# Maven FindBugs plugin

Tags: java, maven-2, maven-plugin, findbugs

You have usage: [findbugs-maven-plugin](http://mojohaus.org/findbugs-maven-plugin/usage.html)

```
<project>
  [...]
  <reporting>
    [...]
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
      <artifactId>findbugs-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>1.2.1</version>
      <configuration>
        <xmlOutput>true|false</xmlOutput>
        <xmlOutputDirectory>directory location of findbugs xdoc xml report</xmlOutputDirectory>
        <threshold>High|Normal|Low|Exp|Ignore</threshold>
        <effort>Min|Default|Max</effort>
        <excludeFilterFile>findbugs-exclude.xml</excludeFilterFile>
        <includeFilterFile>findbugs-include.xml</includeFilterFile>
        <visitors>FindDeadLocalStores,UnreadFields</visitors>
        <omitVisitors>FindDeadLocalStores,UnreadFields</omitVisitors>
        <onlyAnalyze>org.codehaus.mojo.findbugs.*</onlyAnalyze>
        <pluginList>/libs/fb-contrib/fb-contrib-2.8.0.jar</pluginList>
        <debug>true|false</debug>
        <relaxed>true|false</relaxed>
        <findbugsXmlOutput>true|false</findbugsXmlOutput>
        <findbugsXmlOutputDirectory>directory location of findbugs legact xml format report</findbugsXmlOutputDirectory>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
    [...]
  </reporting>
  [...]
</project>
```

But once:

```
mvn site
```

I get:

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] BUILD ERROR
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Failed to resolve artifact.

GroupId: org.codehaus.mojo
ArtifactId: findbugs-maven-plugin
Version: 1.2.1

Reason: Unable to download the artifact from any repository

  org.codehaus.mojo:findbugs-maven-plugin:pom:1.2.1

from the specified remote repositories:
  central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2)
```

Do you know why? What should I do?

Answer (score 6):

Looking at the repository, your version should be 1.2, not 1.2.1

Also, your configuration is wrong, you need to choose some of the options.  So it should look like:

```
    <plugin>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
  <artifactId>findbugs-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.2</version>
  <configuration>
    <threshold>High</threshold>
    <effort>Default</effort>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 2):

try that:

```
<version>1.2</version>
```

http://repo2.maven.org/maven2/org/codehaus/mojo/findbugs-maven-plugin/

Seems like they did a simple copy/paste error.

Answer (score 0):

The report will be in target/site.  Look at the file index.html in a browser, than look for project reports, then findbugs report.

Answer (score 0):

As part of your parent project structure place site.xml into parent-project/src/site:

```
 |--- src 
      |---site
            |---site.xml
```

An example site.xml from "Better Builds with Maven" (a free book available online) should get you started.

Once site.xml is created, execute `mvn site` from the parent project directory. It will pick up your reporting settings including the firebug report. Once the site is built, each child project will have directory /target/site, which contains index.html with a link to project reports. The project reports should contain firebug reports.